# Elements do not fit in the gap constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I study constraint layout. I use the chains for join two textviews tvNameReview and tvTimePeriodReview. But as you can see if text in tvNameReview  is very large, it is superimposed on tvTimePeriodReview. How can I fix it? 
[So it looks like in studio editor][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/COsd8.png Code my layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gl2Review"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin ="20dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gl1Review"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/gl1Review"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gl2Review"
        tools:text="10:15" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space1Review"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/timeReview"/>


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gl3Review"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="20dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/gl3Review"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gl2Review"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/gl3Review"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/gl3Review"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/b1Constraint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="imageView, textView5, textView4"
        app:barrierDirection="left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gl2Review"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewReview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gl2Review"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/space1Review"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/b1Constraint"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNameReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/viewReview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/tvTimePeriodReview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gl2Review"
        tools:text="Very very long name reviewwwww"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTimePeriodReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gl2Review"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tvNameReview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/viewReview"
        tools:text="10:15-11:45"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"/>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using weighted chains.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gl2Review"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin ="20dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gl1Review"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/gl1Review"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gl2Review"
        tools:text="10:15" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space1Review"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/timeReview"/>


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gl3Review"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="20dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/gl3Review"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gl2Review"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/gl3Review"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/gl3Review"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/b1Constraint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="imageView, textView5, textView4"
        app:barrierDirection="left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gl2Review"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewReview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gl2Review"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/space1Review"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/b1Constraint"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNameReview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/viewReview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/tvTimePeriodReview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gl2Review"
        tools:text="Very very long name reviewwwww"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTimePeriodReview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gl2Review"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tvNameReview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/viewReview"
        tools:text="10:15-11:45"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Just set the text views' width to 0dp.